# Android string font is some different format/font

Tags: android, utf-8, fonts

I am calling a web service through async task which is returning text in strange format. here is sample string

```
dhmot_enot = Ï. ÎÎ®Î¼Î¿Ï ÎÎ¿ÏÎ»Î±Ï
zoe_name = Î.Î.Î: ÎÏÎ½ÎµÏ Î ÏÎ¿ÏÏÎ±ÏÎ¯Î±Ï  ÎÏÎ¿ÏÏ Î¥Î¼Î·ÏÏÎ¿Ï
zones_zoe = ÎÎ©ÎÎ Î: ÎÎ ÎÎÎ¥Î¤Î Î Î¡ÎÎ£Î¤ÎÎ£ÎÎ Î¤ÎÎ£ Î¦Î¥Î£ÎÎ£
zoe_fek = 187/Î/2011
fek_rel = 544/Î/1978
yphresia = Î¥.ÎÎÎ  Î. ÎÎ¬ÏÎ·Ï-ÎÎ¿ÏÎ»Î±Ï-ÎÎ¿ÏÎ»Î¹Î±Î³Î¼Î­Î½Î·Ï
```

How to find and resolve this ?

---

**Update 1**

Here is the actual service link that i am calling from server (works well in web browser ) but when i call from android it looks like above

http://geo-polis.gistemp.com/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&srs=EPSG:4326&bbox=23.733829893171787,37.75098946973509,23.839769437909126,37.89294194933182&styles=&&buffer=20&OUTPUTFORMAT=json&request=GetFeatureInfo&layers=geopolis:oria_eniaiou_dhmou&query_layers=geopolis:oria_eniaiou_dhmou&width=1080&height=1832&x=690&y=821

Comment: If it's a webservice, this is not the response you get, this looks like what you've turned it into. Can you please show the actual web service response, including the response headers?

Comment: Thanks and sorry for late . please refer the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is a normal UTF-8 encoded stream of data. To see this, go to the URL you show in your post in the browser, and look at the encoding it picked automatically: it'll show unicode/utf-8 as character encoding for the response. If you change that, forcing the browser to decode it as if it's ANSI encoded (windows codepage 1252/ISO-8859-15) then the text turns into the gibberish you were showing in your question, so: you're not decoding the data correctly, and need to make sure to decode as utf8.